# Does my evidence against the $H_0$ increase with increasing power but fixed $\alpha$? (e.g. with increasing sample size)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

Let's say I test $$H_0: \theta \in [-1,0]  \quad vs. \quad H_1: \theta \in (0,1]$$
where $\Theta = [-1,1]$

and let's say I get a p-value $ p\leq \alpha$. My question is whether the evidence  this result yields against $H_0$ changes with *increasing power* if I employ the *Frequentist perspective*?

From the Bayesian perspective it does. Let $\pi$ be my prior over $\Theta$ and let $\beta(\theta)$ denote the probability of a type two error of my $\alpha$-level test (let's assume for simplicity that the probability of rejecting $H_0$ is a constant $\alpha$ for all $\theta\in [-1, 0]$

The we can caluclate:

$$P(\theta= \theta_1|p \leq  \alpha)= \frac{\int_{(0,1]}(1-\beta(\theta))\pi(\theta)d\theta}{\alpha\int_{[-1,0]}\pi(\theta)d\theta+ \int_{(0,1]}(1-\beta(\theta))\pi(\theta)d\theta}$$

This formula shows that with a decreasing $\beta$ the probability of my alternative being true increases *independent* of my prior (as long as $\int_{[-1,0]}\pi(\theta)d\theta>0)$

However from a frequentist stance I am not so sure whether I can say the same as the evidence against $H_0$ is contained in the p-value for whose calculation we assume that $H_0$ is true and I am not allowed to put a prior over my parameter.

Also taking the interpretation of the p-value being a continuous meausure of evidence against the $H_0 $ does not speak of power at all and seems to suggest that the p-value alone is the measure of evidence against the $H_0$.

Also the answer by Harvey Motulsky in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87800/why-does-one-report-statistical-power-only-when-results-are-non-significant) post claims that a power analysis does not influence the interpreation of a non-significant result.

The problem seems to be that if we assume $\lim_{\theta\to 0^+}\beta(\theta)=\alpha$ the "worst case scenario" does not change even if $\beta(\theta)$ increases for every $\theta \in (0,1]$ e.g. with increasing sample size.

I am somewhat confused and not quite sure how I would anser the question: "does the interpreration of a siginficiant result change with increasing power(and constant alpha)?" (especially in the case of multiple testing where I can be fairly certain that some $H_0$s will be correct and some won't.)

Comment: I say no. Power is the ability to reject a false null hypothesis. Even if your test has low power, say 20%, if you are able to reject, you happened to get lucky and have one of the 20% of times when the test would be rejected.

Comment: But if you would test 50 wrong and 50 correct nulls the proportion of correct rejections of the null increases with power. How would you answer this (which corresponds to the Bayesian calculation in my post)

Comment: It's $\alpha$ that governs how often you reject $H_0$ when $H_0$ is indeed true. If you want to increase the evidence against $H_0$, make it harder to reject, not easier. Think about this: you have one doctor who screens for disease X by diagnosing everyone: 100% power. Another doctor screens for X by doing whatever it is that doctors do, and she catches 15% of patients who have X (misses 25% of patients who have X). If you get diagnosed by the first doctor, okay, she diagnoses everyone. Diagnosed by the second? Yikes! There's much more evidence that you're sick!

Comment: Yes but in my example I assumed that alpha does not change but that the power increases so your example does not apply to this situation. You would have to compare a test with alpha 0.15 and power 1 with a test of 0.15 alpha level and beta 0.25

Comment: Let’s say one doctor has a method that has alpha 0.05 and beta 0.2 vs another doctor that has a method with alpha 0.05 and beta 0.9. in which case would you give more importance to a significant result? For the first method you know that under the alternative you would have been very likely to reject and under the null you would have been very unlikely. In the other case you would have been almost as likely to reject under the alternative as under the null so a significant result is not really that convincing

Comment: Define evidence so that it might be possible to answer! One possibility is evidence as the likelihood ratio?